# Pick only one number from an html page with beatifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this url from coronavirus worldwide and I would like to pick only one number, the newcases in Arizona which is +2383 right now.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
    
url = "https://www.worldmeter.com/coronavirus/us/"
page = requests.get("https://www.worldmeter.com/coronavirus/us/")
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
page.close()
    
newcases = soup.find('a', href_="https://worldmeter.com/coronavirus/arizona", class_="tableRowLinkYellow newCasesStates").get_text(strip=True)
    
print(newcases)
```

I get this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
How do I pick only that number from the whole table? Thank you for your time.

Comment: that content is javascript generated so you would need some kind of headless browser or web driver like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to generate the JS contents

Comment: please show me how to do that. new to python I don't have a clue. thanks

Comment: here a good article on how to use it https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Linh said, it was generated by `Javascript`.Using selenium is an easy way but not efficient enough.(too slow)

You could scrape the API directly:

```
import requests

url = "https://worldmeter.com/coronavirus/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_ninja_tables_public_action&table_id=2582&target_action=get-all-data&default_sorting=old_first"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36",
}

results = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for result in results:
    if result["state_name"] == "Arizona":
        print(result)
        print("The newcases is", result["new_cases"])
```

And this gave me:

```
{'state_name': 'Arizona', 'positive': '275,436', 'new_cases': '2,383', 'death_in_states': '6,302', 'new_deaths': '2', 'recovered_states': '45,400', 'new_recovered': '364', 'totaltestresults': 'Arizona', 'postname': 'arizona', 'cases_100_k_population': '3,866.37', 'state_population': '7278717', 'death_100_k_population': '88.46'}
The newcases is 2,383
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there a possibility to strip the result["new_cases"] in order to have it as an int? Something like result['new_cases].get_text(strip=True) that we usually use in soup? I have to turn it into an int from str. Thank you

Comment: @Daniel That's not hard.You can use `result["new_cases"].replace(",","")` to remove `","`.Then convert it to a integer.So just do `int(result["new_cases"].replace(",",""))`.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get to the url in your code? Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel Press F12 in browser, turn to "Network" tab.Check the data in `XHR` request.And find the necessary data you need.

Comment: Great info. Thank you